# undefined reference in object oriented prgramming

Tags: c++, oop

I'm building a program with 3 different files: geomod.h, geomod.cc and projet.cc, where project.cc uses the functions and classes defined in geomod.h. My problem is in geomod.cc. I don't understand why I have the error "undefined reference" when I define the functions that I prototyped in geomod.cc. I started geomod.h by `namespace geomod{//rest of geomod.h}` . And I started geomod.cc by `using namespace geomod;`.
geomod.h:

```
namespace geomod{
//other function prototypes and classes
void rebouclement(double v, double &vm, double &vp);
//other function prototypes and classes
}
```

geomod.cc:

```
//other #includes
#include "geomod.h"
using namespace geomod;

//code

void rebouclement(double v, double &vm, double &vp) {
    //code
    return;
}
```

I get this compilation error in geomod.cc :
undefined reference to geomod::rebouclement(double,double&,double&)

I tried adding geomod:: before the function in geomod.cc but it doesnt make a difference

Comment: surround definition of  `rebouclement` with namespace scope.

Comment: `geomod::rebouclement` is different from `::rebouclement` in the global scope.